# javafx setDragView(snapshot) sets cursor as "no" symbol

Tags: java, javafx, drag-and-drop, tableview, clipboard

I'm setting up a drag-and-drop system for moving table rows between multiple tableViews in JavaFX.  One feature I want of this system is to set the drag view to be the row you selected.

Here is the relevant code.  I'm setting this in a row factory lambda expression:

```
myTable.setRowFactory(tv -> {
    TableRow<MyThing> row = new TableRow<>();

    row.setOnDragDetected(event -> {
        if (! row.isEmpty()) {
            Integer index = row.getIndex();           
            Dragboard db = row.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.COPY_OR_MOVE);
            ClipboardContent cc = new ClipboardContent();
            cc.putString(index.toString());
            WritableImage snapshot = row.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);
            db.setDragView(snapshot);
            db.setContent(cc);
            event.consume();
        }
    });

    return row;
});
```

The important part is here:

```
WritableImage snapshot = row.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);
db.setDragView(snapshot);
```

Ideally this should take the displayed table row and set it as the drag view.

Instead, however, the drag view displays as a small black [no symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_symbol) (apologies for no screenshot, it replaces the cursor and PrtScr doesn't like that) when click-and-dragging the row.

I think the snapshot isn't working correctly.  But the table displays just fine, and no errors are thrown.  Does anybody have any idea what's going on?  Am I missing some step?

Comment: I think this happens if your target doesn't accept the drop. Have a look in the docs for details: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/drag_drop/jfxpub-drag_drop.htm

Comment: I have dragOver and dragDropped events already, I just ommitted them.  The code works completely fine otherwise, and the functionality of dragging rows between tables total;y functions as intended. The ONLY thing that still doesn't work is the setDragView function, which still doesn't display the snapshot like I would like.